# DropzoneJS hides dropzone area after uploading, how to get it back?

Tags: angular, typescript, dropzone.js

I'm using `angular2-dropzone-wrapper` which I got working almost as I need.

I have this configuration:

```
this.dropZoneConfig = {
    server: this.url,
    maxFilesize: 50,
    acceptedFiles: ".xml",
    parallelUploads: 5,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    createImageThumbnails: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("AccessToken")}
};
```

When I select files to upload I get nicely progress bars.
When all files are uploaded I end up with a large empty block which previously contained the progress bars. I don't see anything because I set `createImageThumbnails: false` which is correct because I'm uploading XML-files and don't need thumbnails.

When all files are finished I want the dropzone to reset. All previously uploaded files are removed and the dropzone area is back.

I've found several examples of using the removeFile(file) method. Which seems to do the trick but the examples are in JavaScript and I'm using TypeScript and can't figure out how to convert it (I'm new to TypeScript).

I do listen to the `QueueComplete`:

```
private onDropZoneQueueComplete(event) {
    console.log("In onDropZoneQueueComplete");
}
```

In here I think I need to call the removeFiles method or call removeFile in the 'Success' event listener.

**EDIT**:
My HTML:

```
  <dropzone [config]="dropZoneConfig" [message]="'Click or drag images here to upload'"
          (error)="onDropZoneUploadError($event)"
          (sendingmultiple)="onDropZoneSendingMultiple($event)"
          (queuecomplete)="onDropZoneQueueComplete($event)"></dropzone>
```

Comment: Paul, I'm not familiar with either dropzone or angular2-dropzone-wrapper but I'd like to help. How do you listen to the `QueueComplete` event? How does your `onDropZoneQueueComplete` get called?

Comment: I've updated my post and added my HTML code.

Using this config property solves my issue of hiding the dropzone area:
`autoReset: 10`
Now when the files are uploaded, they are removed and the dropzone area is shown again.

Comment: Using `autoReset` results is all files canceled even if they are not yet uploaded, resulting in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421311/dropzonejs-is-randomly-skipping-files-to-send-to-the-server
So I need to figure out how to call the removeFiles() method within the Angular2 typescript.

Comment: I see. `autoReset` is also not ideal but it sets an arbitrary time limit (what if your files take longer than 10 seconds to upload?). I'll post the solution I have in mind, please keep me posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dropzone documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) says you need to call `removeFile()` or `removeAllFiles()` on the
Dropzone instance, i.e. `myDropzone.removeAllFiles()`.

But, browsing angular2-dropzone-wrapper's source code I stumbled upon a [reset()](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/blob/master/src/lib/dropzone.directive.ts#L146) method which calls `this.dropzone.removeAllFiles()` for you. SIDE NOTE: When calling `removeAllFiles()`, files that are in the process of being uploaded WILL NOT be removed.

You could call the `reset()` method with the following syntax:

```html
<dropzone #dz (queuecomplete)="dz.reset()"></dropzone>
```

Or, if you have more code to execute on `queuecomplete` you could call a custom method and pass it the reference to the directive (`dz`):

```html
<dropzone #dz (queuecomplete)="onDropZoneQueueComplete($event, dz);"></dropzone>
```

Then in your class:

```ts
private onDropZoneQueueComplete(event, dz) {
  this.filesListComponent.reload();  // additional code
  dz.reset();
}
```

Paul also mentionned he added the following CSS:

```css
.dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing.dz-success.dz-comp‌​lete { display: none !important; }
```

FYI, my initial idea was: let's get a hold of the Dropzone instance created by the dropzone directive! Unfortunately angular2-dropzone-wrapper does NOT let you access the dropzone instance it creates (`this.dropzone` is a private property). Nor does it `exportAs` the instance (which would have let you write something like `<dropzone #mydz="dzinstance"></dropzone>` to get a hold of the dropzone instance in your own `mydz` property).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't know about the `#dz` trick.
I made some small changes: `<dropzone #dz (queuecomplete)="onDropZoneQueueComplete($event, dz);"></dropzone>` because I need to do more when the uploading is completed:

    private onDropZoneQueueComplete(event, dz) {
        this.filesListComponent.reload();
        dz.reset();
    }

And I also added some CSS: 

    .dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing.dz-success.dz-complete {
        display: none !important;
    }

Can you update your answer? I will mark it.

Comment: Ok great. This was my initial code but I simplified it since there was no use for the `$event` in the code you provided. :-) I will update my answer asap. (Note that you're still not using `$event` so you don't **have to** pass it.)